# Open MVC View from _Layout.cshtml when Menu is clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and trying to built a scenario.

1. _Layout.cshtml
2. ABCController
3. ABC\Index.cshtml

I have few menu items in _Layout.cshtml. When I click the Menu item, it should call the ABCController's Index method and it should be the ABC\Index.html. I'm trying to achieve this using jQuery Ajax, get/post methods. The controller's method is called, but the View doesn't open. I'm not sure why it is not being opened. But when I give @Html.ActionLink in the Menu item directly, then the View is opened. My requirement is, I should be able to write javascript to open the View from _Layout.cshtml. I also tried $.get and it won't work. Can someone please help me.

My Code:

Javascript:

```
$("body").on("click", "#aMyLink", function () {
var navURL;
navURL = "/ABC/Index";

$.ajax({
    url: navURL,
    data: {},
    type: 'POST',
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        alert('error occurred - ' + jqXHR.status);
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }
})
```

});

Comment: `$.get()` will not navigate to the new page. If the request is successful `data` in the success function should contain the html for the view you requested.

Comment: I would put the menu in a partial view but I digress.  I think what you seek is a redirect not an ajax call?

Comment: Yes, my menu is in partial view only. I'm not sure if it can be redirect or ajax call, I just wanted the view to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

I think this defeats the purpose of ajax, as an ajax request is meant to avoid doing an entire page cycle. But it can be done by redirecting to the page after a successful call is made.

```
$("body").on("click", "#aMyLink", function () {
    var navURL;
    navURL = "/ABC/Index";

    $.ajax({
        url: navURL,
        data: {},
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            alert('error occurred - ' + jqXHR.status);
        },
        success: function (data) { 
            window.location = navURL;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why bother with `.ajax()` here? You make the same request twice.

Comment: True, but it looks like his requirement is to use ajax.

Comment: Then the "requirement" is wrong and should be re-evaluated.   A lot of people knew to various technologies say "I want to it do this in this way" instead of "how do I get it to do this".  Or could simply be misusing the terminology, "I want to open a view" may mean "I want to open a partial view on the existing page without navigating" - who knows?

Comment: . Thanks for your responses. I tried the way Buggy has done and it works. As you said , I may be using incorrect way. My design is, I have a partial view which has the MENUS, when I click the Menu Item, it should open the new View (which is not partial). Please let me know what approach can I use for this? I can use Url.Action in html, but I wanted to do thru javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("click", "#aMyLink", function () {
    var navURL;
    navURL = "/ABC/Index";
    window.location=navURL;
});
```

NOTE I would likely not hard code this url and put it in the markup as a data element, then use it.

```
<div id="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="mylink" data-url='@Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })'>My Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="mylink" data-url='@Url.Action("someotheraction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })'>My Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then change the code to be:

```
$("#links").on("click", ".mylink", function () {
    window.location=$(this).data("url");;
});
```

Comment: This approach is good, it works! But just wanted to check if this is right way?

Comment: Not knowing more regarding your solution, I would think the second part (html and code) would be something you could use/build upon - especially if you put it in a partial view for your menu to make it maintainable.